# Is there any hidden 'W' sound after 'comment' in : Comment est-elle?

Tags: prononciation

*Comment est-il?*

I don't know why, even tho I know that there is no linking 'W' sound in French as there is in English I still hear it between 'comment' and 'est' as if it were (/kɔ.mɑ̃  *w*  ɛt.i.l/) and it has been driving me crazy so I'm wondering if what I hear is correct.

Here is a link to a video where I think the 'W' sound is pronounced when 'comment est-il' is said :
https://youtu.be/V98BvCQrVeM

Note: I am not sure about the phonetic transcript. Feel free to correct it if it contains any mistakes.

Comment: There is not the least trace of a w sound after "comment" in either of the sources you mention; I've listened repeatedly; that is very strange. All that can be heard from Google translate is the somewhat blurred pronunciation of "il" (almost "i" instead of "il"). [google](https://www.bing.com/search?q=google+translate&form=PRFRFR&pc=UE00&httpsmsn=1&refig=f2d750aefedc48eb8989fb317deaec19&sp=-1&pq=google+translate&sc=8-16&qs=n&sk=&cvid=f2d750aefedc48eb8989fb317deaec19)

Comment: Also, while the speaker in that video doesn't have any sort of -strong- accent, I'd guess they were not native speakers.  That might be messing with your ear.

Comment: +1 pour la vidéo :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In both the video and Google Translate's pronunciation, I think I understand what you're hearing. It seems to be an implicit glide between the /ɑ̃/ and the /ɛ/ simply as a function of the first being further back: [/ɑ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_unrounded_vowel) is open back, whereas [/ɛ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) is open-mid front.

If a speaker is not very careful to articulate each sound distinctly (as is normal in spoken language), you can get a "legato" effect. The tongue makes essentially the same motion by moving from back to front as it would make if you were intentionally articulating a /w/.<sup>1</sup>

However, /w/ is also [labial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_labio-velar_approximant) and that feature is absent in both of those unrounded vowels, so it's not a full /w/. At least, that's true of the **canonical** vowels. One [seemingly linguistically informed and France-centred resource](http://web.archive.org/web/20160128183030/http://pronouncefrench.net/vowels/nasalized-vowels/the-vowel-of-dans/) claims that many French speakers do actually do some light lip-rounding on the first vowel.

I personally find it hard to tell whether rounding is happening based on your video, but it would better explain your perception of /w/. In any case, if you slow the video down to 0.5x speed, you'll hear more clearly what's happening.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The phenomenon of two consecutive vowels is called [hiatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiatus_(linguistics)). If not resolved, it can lead to just this sort of confusion. One way to resolve it is a brief [glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop), perceived as a pause between the vowels. Also common in French is [liaison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(linguistics)), at least where it's syntactically possible.</sub>

Comment: So if I understood correctly, in the video and Google Transelate's pronunciation there is a /w/ sound but it is not a full /w/ sound though   because such sound require the lips and I should be careful ,when saying such sentence,  to not say neither a /w/ sound or a half /w/ sound and to use a glottal stop instead or a liaison ,if it's possible.

Comment: @Manar The best way is probably not to think about it at all. If you make those vowels right, you'll get the same effects automatically -- and native speakers won't be listening for it anyway, possibly not even aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

You answered your own question: there is not and there is no reason why there would be. Where did you hear this -- is this some specific accent perhaps?

Comment: Maybe as I sometimes hear it and sometimes not. Here in this video, for example, I hear it. https://youtu.be/V98BvCQrVeM

Comment: @Manar Can you add that link to the question please?

Comment: In addition, when I typed it on 'google transelate' and listened to the audio of it being pronounced I heard the 'W' sound. I even recorded the audio and tried to hear it in a slower speed and still heard it.